# Can't connect to SQL Database from Azure Application Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have two Application Services running .NET Core 3.1 apps that connect to an Azure SQL Database. One app is a simple test app to test connectivity to the database using the same DI pipeline, the other is the full application.  The test application connects to the database and produces the desired output while the production application fails to connect with the following exception message:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

I've modified the rules on the database to include my development workstations IP address and both applications connect to the database as expected.  On the database firewall, I've also done the following:

1. Added the IP address for the test and production apps to the database firewall.  It's the IP address designated as `virtual ip address` in the properties section of the App Service.  The two app services share a virtual IP address.
2. Enabled the `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` setting in the console.

The applications' `appsettings.json` files are identical.

When I deploy the test app to the production server it still works.  Something in the production app is causing the connection to fail. Why can't the production app connect and what else can be done to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: you need to allow `Additional Outbound IP Addresses` - If you are using App Service without VNet integration, then it can use any of those IP addresses. You never know which one ;)

Comment: @CarlosGarcia Thanks for the suggestion, it sounds like I need to set up a virtual network. I would have thought that allowing connections from Azure would have taken care of the additional outbound IP addresses. There are like 20 of them! Adding all of those for each application service that needs the DB is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: I thought that should work as well. When you go to Properties, the `Virtual IP address` is the inbound address. The outbound addresses in use are `Outbound IP addresses`, and the `Additional` are other IP addresses that could be used if anything happens (like a host gets updated). If you want to use VNet, then you have to use `VNet integration`, since these are outbound connections. Let me know if it does not work

Comment: Thanks for the help @CarlosGarcia, I figured out the problem which was a configuration error that I didn't pick up on until I added some more verbose logging.

Comment: Makes sense. Most people with those errors is a typo in the connection string :)   If you haven't, take a look at Managed Service Identity, it simplifies things a bit

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if there was something wrong with my connection string, I added some logging to write it out to the log file.  I realized the connection string was wrong - it was trying to connect to a different database.  AppSettings.Production.json was overriding the connection string, my test app had an empty AppSettings.Production.json which is why it worked.